# why my penalty function works in this case?

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I am using a python module called "PyGAD". I am trying to see the [possible 45 numbers between [14,99] that makes an average of 59.32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3tEu.png). Instead of using `gene_space = range(14, 99)` nor  setting `init_range_low = 14`, `init_range_high = 99`, I wanted to try to force the solutions into that range by implementing a penalty function.

```
def lgt(x, a=17, b=99):
    greaterThan = numpy.where(x < a, 0, 1)
    lessThan = numpy.where(x <= b, 1, 0)
    return numpy.where(x * greaterThan * lessThan == 0, -10000+x, x)
```

[and it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UV2C7.png) works, but why? (the more negative it is the faster fitness converges.)

I've also tried (x+100)^4, which would make more sense because it would easily create an outliner and forces the algorithm to migrate to range [14,99] to get a higher score. Yet, it didn't work (why?). As to functions such as [x otherwise 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeYEr.png) makes no sense because it doesn't provide a sense of direction.

here's my full code:

```
import pygad
import numpy

desired_output = 59.32

#hyper params
#init_range_low / high is [-50, 50] to test the penalty function. I.E. solutions will
#free of negative numbers, and some solutions will go up to 50 but below 99. 
#Mutation rate (and related params) set to high to decrease num generation needed. 
#num_genes = 45 because we want to take average of 45 numbers
num_generations = 10000
num_parents_mating = 25
sol_per_pop = 41
num_genes = 45
init_range_low = -50
init_range_high = 50
parent_selection_type = "sus"
keep_parents = 3
crossover_type = "single_point"
mutation_type = "random"
mutation_percent_genes = 60

#penlity function
#the more negative the number, the better the result
def lgt(x, a=14, b=99):
    greaterThan = numpy.where(x < a, 0, 1)
    lessThan = numpy.where(x <= b, 1, 0)
    return numpy.where(x * greaterThan * lessThan == 0, -10000+x, x)

#fitness function
def fitness_func(solution, solution_idx):
    output = numpy.sum(solution*function_inputs)
    fitness = 1.0 / numpy.abs(output - desired_output)
    return fitness

fitness_function = fitness_func

ga_instance = pygad.GA(num_generations=num_generations,
                       num_parents_mating=num_parents_mating,
                       fitness_func=fitness_function,
                       sol_per_pop=sol_per_pop,
                       num_genes=num_genes,
                       init_range_low=init_range_low,
                       init_range_high=init_range_high,
                       parent_selection_type=parent_selection_type,
                       keep_parents=keep_parents,
                       crossover_type=crossover_type,
                       mutation_type=mutation_type,
                       mutation_percent_genes=mutation_percent_genes)

ga_instance.run()

solution, solution_fitness, solution_idx = ga_instance.best_solution()
print("Parameters of the best solution : {solution}".format(solution=solution))
prediction = numpy.average(solution)
print("Predicted output based on the best solution : {prediction}".format(prediction=prediction))
```

Comment: I actually discovered that -10000+(x**3) helps converge even faster at 1500 cycles. It makes sense because x^3  makes the outliner more standout while retaining the sign. Tho, still couldn't figure out why the parent function works. Sign shouldn't matter as we're taking the absolute difference to calculate fitness.